# How to integrate google-drive with google apps using API…?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-apps

i need to know how to open google drive files in google apps(like actual google drive file open) with API.Please give me an idea to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate your application in Google Drive, first you need to enable the Drive API and provide configuration details in your API project and this part of [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/enable-sdk#enable_the_drive_api) will explain you with that.

Then the Drive UI Integration part will contains fields to enter information describing your application. The Application Name and Short Description fields are displayed to users in the Manage apps dialog in the Drive UI

Go to **Drive API**, then after you enable, you can see the **Drive UI Integration** tab.

For the Opening of files, this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/integrate-open) will help you on that. There is also a sample code here that will serve as a guide on you.